# getting error while creating tables using db.create_all() between two tables with one-many relationship

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I have 2 tables  between which I created one-many relationship, but while importing db object and using db.create_all() I get the below error

> sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with
>   column 'addresses.user_id' could not find table 'user' with which to
>   generate a foreign key to target column 'id'

The full code is below

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///relationships.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Address(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'addresses'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email_address = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)

    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

    user = db.relationship("User", back_populates="addresses")

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Address(email_address='%s')>" % self.email_address

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    fullname = db.Column(db.String(50))
    nickname = db.Column(db.String(50))

    addresses = db.relationship("Address", back_populates="user")

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<User(name='%s', fullname='%s', nickname='%s')>" % (
                                self.name, self.fullname, self.nickname)
```

If you can point out the mistake, that would be great help. Thanks for reading my question.

Answer (score 0):

I just commented out the table names in both classes and it started working.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///relationships.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Address(db.Model):
    # __tablename__ = 'addresses'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email_address = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)

    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

    user = db.relationship("User", back_populates="addresses")

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Address(email_address='%s')>" % self.email_address

class User(db.Model):
    # __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    fullname = db.Column(db.String(50))
    nickname = db.Column(db.String(50))

    addresses = db.relationship("Address", back_populates="user")

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<User(name='%s', fullname='%s', nickname='%s')>" % (
                                self.name, self.fullname, self.nickname)
```